# Interpreting Neo4j Returned Records

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

The return scheme for Cypher queries has generally been complex, but I am especially confused on how to access the integer result of a returned `count`. Is the wrong number showing up or I am I accessing the result in the wrong way?

Query:

```
MATCH (self:USER {userID: $userID})-[r:FRIEND]-(other:USER) RETURN count(other)
```

Logged Record:

```
Record {
    keys: [ 'count(other)' ],
    length: 1,
    _fields: [ [Integer] ],
    _fieldLookup: { 'count(other)': 0 }
}
```

I called `_fieldLookup` and logged the result:

```
{ 'count(other)': 0 }
```

I know for a fact that the actual count is 2, as I can visually verify my database through the neo4j browser. Is the query simply wrong or I am accessing it in the wrong way?

I would also appreciate any docs on the return schema for cypher queries. I haven't found anything that discusses that yet.

EDIT: Screenshot of Graph

[image: graph]

I was testing my query on "userID_2", who does in fact have two friends. I also tried this query on some other users in the database, and while some do in fact have zero, the query always returned:

```
{ 'count(other)': 0 }
```

EDIT 2:

I tried logging this

```
console.log(result.records[0].get(0));
```

But got this strange result:

```
Integer { low: 2, high: 0 }
```

2 is the correct count for my query, though I am confused why `high` exists.

Comment: Could you share  a screenshot of the graph from the browser where you're verifying the count? Then it will be easier to see what's wrong with the query. `count` definitely works, so it's possible that it is the query that is off

Comment: About the return schema, do you mean specifically for the Neo4j Node.js driver or in general?

Comment: I guess both.. I am working in Node.js but I assume that the structure in which Cypher outputs info is similar across drivers

Comment: @SimonThordal edited to include screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const count = executeResult.records[0].get(0);
```

It gets the value from a record by the index or by field key [reference](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/4.3/class/lib6/record.js%7ERecord.html)

Comment: Edited post. What's up with `low` and `high`?

Comment: @JohnSorensen It's a wrapper around the number because Neo4j supports higher precision of numbers, call `value.toNumber();` on it.

Comment: @JohnSorensen could you try calling `toInt()` after `executeResult.records[0].get(0)`? This should get you the integer value

Comment: both `value.toNumber()` and `value.toInt()` worked for me. What are the differences between those two methods?